# WooCommerce: Removing product write panel tab

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I’m using WooCommerce and I’d like to hide the "Linked Products" tab in the backend. I found a hook to add tabs (`woocommerce_product_write_panel_tabs`) but I’m not sure if it’s also possible to hide certain tabs with this hook.

Thanks for any help!

[image: Product write panel tab]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following to the wp-admin.min.css should remove the linked products.

```
li.linked_product_options.linked_product_tab
{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

So I had the same issue. Woocommerce provides a filter (just as they do about everything else) that can handle this. The filter is 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs'.

```
function remove_linked_products($tabs){
    unset($tabs['linked_product']);
    return($tabs);
}
add_filter('woocommerce_product_data_tabs', 'remove_linked_products', 10, 1);
```

This will remove the linked products tab. You can also unset the other tabs using their array index. Below is a copy of the filter application from class-wc-meta-box-product-data.php.

```
$product_data_tabs = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_product_data_tabs', array(
    'general' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'General', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'general_product_data',
        'class'  => array( 'hide_if_grouped' ),
    ),
    'inventory' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Inventory', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'inventory_product_data',
        'class'  => array( 'show_if_simple', 'show_if_variable', 'show_if_grouped' ),
    ),
    'shipping' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Shipping', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'shipping_product_data',
        'class'  => array( 'hide_if_virtual', 'hide_if_grouped', 'hide_if_external' ),
    ),
    'linked_product' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Linked Products', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'linked_product_data',
        'class'  => array(),
    ),
    'attribute' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Attributes', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'product_attributes',
        'class'  => array(),
    ),
    'variations' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Variations', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'variable_product_options',
        'class'  => array( 'variations_tab', 'show_if_variable' ),
    ),
    'advanced' => array(
        'label'  => __( 'Advanced', 'woocommerce' ),
        'target' => 'advanced_product_data',
        'class'  => array(),
    )
));
```

So just substitute the unset($tabs['linked_product'] with whichever tab you want to remove from the backend.

Comment: This is great for making simpler editor screens for non admins, like vendors etc. as this allows them to upload and manage their own products much more easily than via the front end!